# For converting video to frames, should I do client or server side processing?

Tags: reactjs, node.js, ffmpeg

Here is the thing, I have a Nodejs API that serves one video at a time when client request it.

The client (made in react) receives the video, which has no more than 15 seconds, watch it and decide if he wants to approve or deny it.
If he approves the video, it must be displayed in a sort of frames carousel, with one frame per second, so there is no more than 15 images/frames.

So the question is, should I do the conversion video-to-frames on client once he approves the video or should I do it on server-side and then request each frame (or streaming all frames with one request if possible)?

Now, I'm doing the conversion on server with ffmpeg, but it seems tricky to send all the frames when the client already have them inside the video.